# Synergy: weirdness when moving the mouse from one desktop to the next

Tags: windows-xp, synergy, ubuntu-11.10

I have two desktop pc's, set up as follows:

- Left: Ubuntu 11.10, 2 screens, vertically oriented. Synergy server (version 1.3.6, installed from the official repos), starts at login.
- Right: Windows XP, 1 screen, vertically oriented. Synergy client (version 1.3.7), starts when the computer starts.

The weirdness happens when I want to move the mouse from left to right. I can only do it when a window is aligned to the right edge of the Ubuntu desktop. If the desktop is showing, the mouse just stops there and won't go over to the Windows desktop. What's more: if a Window covers only half the screen, say the top half, then I can move over only at the top half of the screen, where the window intersects with the edge of the destkop. Fortunately, I can always cross over at the top right corner of the screen -- presumably because that's where the Ubuntu menu bar is.

I can't figure out why this happens, or how to fix it. I tried re-installing Synergy, but that didn't help. I installed it from the Ubuntu 11.10 repos. On Windows, I'm running version 1.3.7.

Bonus question: if I hit the Windows key when I'm working on the Windows machine, then the Ubuntu Dash will show as soon as I move back to the Ubuntu box...

Comment: I suggest you to update your windows version of synergy to 1.3.8, which is the latest stable version and if that does not help, to the 1.4.5 beta.

Comment: @MichaelK Yep, that seems to solve it, thanks! If you write this down in an answer, I will accept it :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, I suggest you to update your windows version of synergy to 1.3.8, which is the latest stable version and if that does not help, to the 1.4.5 beta.

Comment: 1.3.8 did the trick.